# Button to allow ADB backup not working

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb

I have a Oneplus One running CyanogenMod 12.0. (Based on Lollipop 5.0) I'm trying to create a backup using ADB. I executed the command, and it gave me the usual prompt to unlock my phone and allow the backup. On my phone, the screen comes up asking me if I want to encrypt the backup with a password, and with the "Do not back up" and "Back up my data" buttons. So far so good.

The "Do not back up" button works fine: When I click it, the command on my computer stops running. But the Confirm button just does nothing. When I tap the button, nothing happens; the button doesn't even "light up" like buttons normally do.

- The button is not "grayed out" or disabled: It looks exactly like the other, functioning, cancel button.
- I tried inputting a password, thinking maybe it would not allow me to back up my data unencrypted, but it still behaved exactly the same
- I tried running the "adb backup" command with literally every combination of arguments, with the same results
- "adb devices" does show my phone properly connected

How can I either

- Fix this, and make an ADB backup
- Make a complete backup in some other way, without root access. (I want to unlock my bootloader, which wipes all data)

Comment: 1. "*When I tap the button, nothing happens*" -- so what exactly happens on computer's screen when you tap "Back up my Data" button? // 2. Does the command exits abruptly like when it does for "Do not back up"? // 3.  Did you ever create Desktop backup password from Developer Settings of Android some time earlier when using the device?

Comment: 1. Nothing. 2. No, nothing happens. It just stays on the "Unlock phone" prompt. 3. No, I never made a password.

Comment: Just asking out of curiosity: have you taken a look at [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices)?

Comment: I have now, and I followed exactly the steps of the accepted answer, resulting in the exact same problem as in my original question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me force stopping the Facebook Messenger seemed to fix the problem.
In your case it might be related to a different app.

Go to Settings->Apps->Select the application you suspect->Press "FORCE STOP"

Possibly this is related to the "draw over other apps" privilege.

Also see http://forums.androidcentral.com/htc-one-s/520618-adb-backup-can-t-click-back-up-my-data-button-phone.html

Comment: try adding a picture to the answer to elucidate your point

Comment: it was Twilight in my case (paused and it worked)

Comment: I could not press the "Back up my data" button either on a Samsung Galaxy S3. For me I think it was a screen adjuster app that dims the screen. Stopped it after reading the hint here and the button worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Lance Which screen adjuster app was it?